# Joins between different entities without defined relation causing unexpected results using Doctrine2

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I've got two entities, with a "logical" 1:1 relation which is, however, not configured (they don't know they're related to each other).

I can't just configure this relation because there's a lot of older code depending on this situation (see below for further explanation).

Now, I'm trying to resolve this relation manually using a simple `SELECT` query with a `LEFT JOIN` clause:

```
SELECT E1 as my_cool_entity_1, E2 as my_cool_entity_2
FROM Namespace\Of\Entity1 E1
LEFT JOIN Namespace\Of\Entity2 E2
WITH E2.someColumn = E1.someOtherColumn
```

In my case, there is exactly one row matching `E1` and one row matching the join on `E2`. Somehow, I've used Doctrine in that way earlier, but I can't remember where and how. The result expected is an array like this:

```
[0 => [
    "my_cool_entity_1" => (Instance of E1),
    "my_cool_entity_2" => (Instance of E2)
]]
```

Instead, the array looks like this:

```
[0 => [
        "my_cool_entity_1" => (Instance of E1)
    ], 
 1 => [
        "my_cool_entity_2" => (Instance of E2)
]]
```

How is it possible to make Doctrine hydrate the array as I'm expecting it? Thanks in advance!

Note: I wrote that I can't define the relation between these 2 entities. That's because, if a relation is defined, Doctrine requires you to assign the **instance** of `E2` to `E1` when saving E1 -- in my older code, however, I'm only assigning the related **ID**. Thus, Doctrine would ignore `E2` at all and cause constraints errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without a definition of the relation doctrine can not know that it's a oneToOne relation so the result will always be a collection. you need to write your own hydrator to achieve this.